# How to create .env multiline variable

Tags: docker, shell, environment-variables

The title may be a bit confusing, so a little explanation.
I need to configure an application by passing a PKCS1 PEM encoded key using environment variable.
The App is configured using a `.env` file

Locally I just `export MY_ENV_VAR=$(cat my_key.pem)`, but on the server, it needs to be inside the `.env` file and needs to contain the value, not a command.

I've tried

```
echo MY_ENV_VAR=`awk 'NF {sub(/\n/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' my_key.pem` >> .env
```

But the generated string was not accepted by the application I'm trying to set up, it complains that the key is not PKCS1/8 compliant.

For now, I've added the `export MY_ENV_VAR=$(cat my_key.pem)` to my `.profile` and I launch it manually, but I would prefer to just keep the config in the `.env`.

How can I do this? I'm currently running `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` but I am fine to switch to other shell if needs be.

Comment: Wrap it in single quotes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457787/how-to-export-a-multi-line-environment-variable-in-bash-terminal-e-g-rsa-privat

Comment: unfortunately this does not work in my case.

Comment: you have to open the first quote and press enter, it'll go to the next line, when you add the closing quote and press enter it'll assign the value

Comment: @Bat0u89 the question is about .env file, not bash or other terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
MY_ENV_VAR=$(cat <<EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF
)
```

Be aware that "EOF" needs to be in its own line, nothing after or before, so you need to close the parenthesis in the next line.

You can replace "EOF" by other word, that will be the "closing quote".

This way, your source/env file doesn't depend on filesystem contents and is self-contained.